# useMutation always returns data undefined

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

this my code

**React**

```
const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  mutation {
    signUp(lastName: "Amasia")
  }
`;
const HandlerRequest = () => {
  const [loading, { data }] = useMutation(EXCHANGE_RATES);

  console.log('apollo', data);

  return <p>apollo</p>;
};
```

**Schema**

```
  gql`
  extend type Mutation {
    signUp(
      lastName: String!
    ): String!
  }
`;
```

**Resolvers**

```
Mutation: {
    signUp: async (
      _,
      { lastName}
    ) => {
      try {
        console.log(lastName)
        return lastName;    
      } catch (error) {
        return 'error';
      }
    },
  },
```

useMutation always returns data undefined but at graphql playground are working.what am i doing netak ?.

Answer (score 2):

useMutation should return a function to call to execute the mutation. Generally you would hook this up to a button or something. It seems a little odd to use a mutation that executes automatically when the component loads.

```
const HandlerRequest = () => {
  const [getExchangeRates, { data }] = useMutation(EXCHANGE_RATES);
  // Load data if not already loaded.
  if (!data) { getExchangeRates(); }
  console.log('apollo', data);

  return <p>apollo</p>;
};
```

Using the above you'll likely see two console.logs.

1. The initial component render, should be undefined
2. When getExchangeRates returns and data updates the component will be rerendered and the log will be called again.

Comment: I use your example I will get eternal cycle.means through a function call it is possible to make Mutation request. instant call impossible?

Comment: @Jesus you probably want to do it in a higher order component and render this component with the resulting data.

Comment: this doesn't work at all, the if statement is never true, so it never fires the mutation. Where in the documentation dos it show that this is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the onCompleted callback and remember to pass the data object:

```
  const [loading, { data }] = useMutation(EXCHANGE_RATES, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of useMutation is not quite correct. Here is the correct usage.
You also need to execute the mutation. `data` will be undefined until then.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [doExchangeRates, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
    EXCHANGE_RATES,  
    onCompleted: (data) => {  console.log({data});  }
); 

  return <p onClick={doExchangeRates} >apollo</p>;
};
```

You can see full docs on useMutation [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#executing-a-mutation).